# сравнение способов получения случайных чисел

Tags: c++

Хочу понять  каким образом лучше получать случайные числа, ну например для 
какой то игры. По этому поводу прошу у вас помощь. Чтобы я это хорошо себя представлял, обьясните пожалуйста мне на простом примере что лучше и почему.

```
class Random_numbers {
    int m, s;
public:
    Random_numbers(int max, int start = 0) : m(max + 1), s(start) {}
    int operator ()() { return rand() % m + s; }
};

int main()
{    
    const int N = 20, r = 100;
    std::vector<int> v(2 * r);
    auto f = v.begin(), end = v.end();
    std::generate(f, end, []() { static int n = -100; return ++n;});
    std::random_shuffle(f,end);
    std::copy_n(f, N, ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    // второй способ
    Random_numbers Rn(2 * r, -100);
    int number = 0;
    srand(time(0)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        number = Rn();
        std:: cout << number <<' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Чем отличаются эти 2 способа и какой способ выдаст результат предпочтительней и почему? Если  вопросов слышком много, мне устроит и ответ только на первый вопрос

Comment: Предпочтительнее воспользоваться библиотекой <random>...

Comment: то есть там есть определенные классы для случайных чисел, или что?

Comment: Там есть генераторы и распределения, которые объединяются вместе для выдачи таких случайных чисел, которые нужны - скажем так, существенно богаче и надежнее, чем `rand()`.

Comment: @Harry,  это какраз то что нужно, а то   не очень приятная для меня тема, и я не знал об этом:  будем пользоваться тем что есть

Comment: Это большая тема... Вкратце - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: @Harry,   да, я  без всяких сомнений  воспользуюсь вашим советом, спасибо и удачи вам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У этих способов есть принципиальное отличие. В первом Вы генерируете массив неповторяющихся чисел, перемешиваете его и последовательно выводите первые N элементов этого массива. Т.е. выведенные элементы **гарантированно** не будут повторяться.

Во втором случае Вы выводите N случайно сгенерированных чисел, лежащих в каком-то диапазоне. Будут ли эти числа все попарно-различны или будут повторяться - этого не знает никто. Вероятность повторения прямо пропорциональна числу сгенерированных чисел и обратно пропорциональна числу возможных чисел (фактически - ширине диапазона)

Comment: а качество распределения функции rand() , кроме того что числа могут повторяться?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Нет смысла говорить о качестве распределения на 20 элементах. Сгенерируйте 5000 элементов, подсчитайте частоту выпадения каждого и оцените качество распределения

Comment: так и сделаю, спасибо

Comment: я наверное  плохо сформулировал вопрос,  потому что в вашем ответе я  прочитал не все, что мне нужно, но так как он мне помог разобраться, я его приму